# is it possible to connect two PCIe endpoint directly for just high-speed comunnication purpose?

Tags: pci-e, soc

I'm currently trying to design a system where two identical SoC chips interact with each other.

I want to read and write each other's chip memory using PCIe.

As far as I know, since the two chips are identical, I can't designate one as the root complex.

So, I want to design both PCIe ports as endpoints.

Is this way wrong? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You want a non-transparent bridge (NTB). https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ntb.txt

Comment: As far as I understand, to implement NTB, each chip must have Rootport of RootComplex and Endpoint for Bridge.
It seems that when connecting two devices via PCIe, it is necessary for one device to function as a Root port and the other as an Endpoint, even if it's just for a two-device connection.
Thank you for comments.